# dynamically update comments next to pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which shows a list of products. Each product shows info such as current stock level, current demand for that product, etc.
What I would like to do is to make notes next to that overview (so outside of the pivot table) for each product stating for example the reason why stock is low for a certain product, what we will do about it and who will be responsible for that (3 columns).

However I would like to have these comments "linked" to each product. Meaning, if I adjust the filter in the pivot table, that the comments I just wrote, shift to the right product line in the pivot. The comments which are not relevant to the current filter selection should not be lost, but should appear whenever the linked product pops up again in the pivot table.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Store comments in the separate sheet, in a table containing product names in the first column and comments in the following. Then use VLOOKUP to display comments in right places next to the pivot table. Turn off Generate GetPivotData from the pivot table options before you construct relevant VLOOKUP formula.

Comment: well comments need to be next to the pivot table. What I do now is - whenever I close the file copy pastes the product and comments in a seperate sheet. whenever I open the file the data gets put in the right place with a vlookup after refreshing the pivot. But this does not give me the flexibility of slicing the pivot whenever I want.

Comment: left some free columns between the pivot tab and the column with formula. Try to have product name (or ID or whatever) in the same column all the time. That's all.